# Внедрение сторонней DLL в процесс - AutoIt

Tags: windows, файлы, winapi, dll, autoit

Всем привет, имеется x32 инжектор, x64 DLL и x64 процесс.

Инжектор: _autoitscript.com/forum/topic/109237-injectau3/

Итак, при инжекте скомпилированным **под х64** скриптом х64ой DLL в x64 процесс - всё идёт как по маслу.
При инжекте скомпилированным **под х86** скриптом х64ой DLL в x64 процесс - получаю "GetExitCodeThread failed", т.е либа и процесс всегда одни и те же, меняется лишь разрядность инжектора.

Также ещё пробовал некоторые инжекторы - результат тот же самый. В чём проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Специалисты говорят, что WriteProcessMemory не будет работать ни в варианте x86->x64, ни обратно. В MSDN четкого обоснования я найти не могу, увы.

Comment: Т.е внедрить свою длл по схеме, описанной выше, никак не получится?

Comment: @givemepoison получится, но процесс должен иметь ту же битность, что и жертва.

Comment: Нашё вот такую вещь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297452/x86-code-injection-into-an-x86-process-from-a-x64-process   Вкратце понял, что можно не заморачиваться с разрядностью процесса